# Can't publish .NET Core project for linux-64

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, publish

Whenever I try to publish my c# .NET Core project for linux-64 for my raspberry pi running raspbian, I get this error:

```
04/05/2018 19:26:10
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__108.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---

===================
```

Comment: Can you please include `dotnet --info` output as well as `dotnet publish` command you're using. If you publish from VS, please try to reproduce the problem from command-line using `dotnet publish`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by running the command: `dotnet publish linux-arm`.